# Prove that $\frac{ 5^{125}-1}{ 5^{25}-1}$ is a composite number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that   $\dfrac {\left( 5^{125}-1\right)}{\left( 5^{25}-1\right)}$ is composite number using number theory. Do not use calculator or Wolfram alpha or anything like that.

Comment: What is composite number?

Comment: A composite number is an integer which is NOT a prime number.

Comment: if $x=5^{25}$ then your formula gives $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ right?

Comment: Yes! correct. Go ahead.

Comment: @AkshayHegde use that fact with this answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383379/prove-that-x-1-divides-xn-1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ The factorization arises by applying a variation of cyclotomic factorization known as *Aurifeuillian* factorization (aka Aurifeuillean). For the OP we can employ the following one

$$\begin{align}\frac{(5x^2)^5-1}{5x^2-1} =\, (25x^4\!+15x^2+1)^2 - (5x(5x^2\!+1))^2\\[4pt]
\overset{\large x\, =\, 5^{\large 12}}\Longrightarrow\ \ \frac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1}\, =\, (5^{50}+3\cdot 5^{25}+1)^2 - (5^{13}(5^{25}+1))^2\end{align}$$

**Remark** $\ $ There are many known Aurifeuillian factorizations (e.g. see below for a few more). For more see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119812/242) and see [Aurifeuillian Factorization](http://www.ams.org/mcom/2006-75-253/S0025-5718-05-01766-7/S0025-5718-05-01766-7.pdf) by A. Granville and P. Pleasants.

$$\begin{align} 
\frac{(3x^2)^3+1}{3x^2+1} &=\, (3x^2\!+1)^2-(3x)^2\\[4pt]
\frac{(5x^2)^5-1}{5x^2-1} &=\, (25x^4\!+15x^2+1)^2 - (5x)^2(5x^2\!+1)^2\\[4pt]
\frac{(7x^2)^7+1}{7x^2+1} &=\, (7x^2\!+1)^6-(7x)^2(49 x^4\!+7x^2+1)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 17):

This is problem $87$ of Putnam and Beyond. Here is the solution:

$\dfrac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1}=1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4$ where $a=5^{25}$.

We have $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5=(a^2+3a+1)^2-(5^{13}(a+1))^2=(a^2+3a+1+5^{13}(a+1))(a^2+3a+1-5^{13}(a+1))$

The reason the second factor is larger than $1$ is $a^2=5^{50}>5^{39}>5^{13}(a+1)$

---

This problem was also part of the 1992 imo shortlist and was proposed by Korea, here is a link with the same solution but shorter: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh9216.html

Comment: Wow, now how were you expected to realize that as a difference of squares in the first place?  Is it just a puzzle-math mantra that that's one of the first things you try on such a problem?

Comment: I don't know, I think the point of the problem is to get to $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4$ and then try to factor it appropriately for a long time (using the fact that you know the value of $a$).

Comment: @gamamal Thanks a lot for the solution and citing the source. I came across it in a local math competition.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Wow, those are some hardcore local competitions !

Comment: (+1) @Gamamal, the trick was to show that $1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4 = xy$ as in can be written as a product of two other numbers? Which would show it isnt prime? 

Another Question - Can proof by contradiction be used in such cases?

Comment: Yes, that was the trick, if $n$ is the product of two numbers larger than $1$ then $n$ can't be prime. Proceeding by contradiction without using this trick seems hard, because you would have to assume the number is prime and reach a contradiction, but assuming the number is prime does not help us reach any other interesting observations in this case, which is what we need to reach a contradiction in the end.

Comment: This is a special case of a general class of factorizations - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$

and $5^{25}=(5^5)^5$, whilst $5^{125}=((5^5)^5)^5$

Does this get you anywhere?

Comment: $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ can be prime, for example when x = 7. So now you figure out why x = $5^{25}$ is special.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = 525$. Then $\frac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1} = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+3^x+1)^2 - 5x(x+1)^2$ which has factor $(x^2+3x+1-513x-513)$ which is obviously $> 1$ and $< x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.