# Prove $\frac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1}$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Prove $\displaystyle \frac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1}$ is not a prime.

Some obvious thoughts:

$\displaystyle \frac{5^{125}-1}{5^{25}-1}={(5^{25})}^4+{(5^{25})}^3+{(5^{25})}^2+{5^{25}}+1$

**UPD:** A similar question: [Prove that $\frac{ 5^{125}-1}{ 5^{25}-1}$ is a composite number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345662/prove-that-dfrac-left-5125-1-right-left-525-1-right-is-composit)

Comment: For a prime $p$, $\phi(p)=p-1$ and it is equal to $(1-\frac1{p_1})(1-\frac1{p_2})...(1-\frac1{p_n})$

Comment: Maybe we need some factorization tricks to represent the formula instead of finding a specific prime which could divide it.

Comment: $a^n-b^n=(a-b)...$

Comment: You need some trick because the factorization is $3597751×28707251×4032808198751×767186663625251×24687045214139234043375683501$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Could we use $a^n-b^n=(a-b)\dots$ trick to ${5^{25}}^4+{5^{25}}^3+{5^{25}}^2+{5^{25}}+1$?

Comment: I think you should change those $5^{25}$ to $(5^{25})$.

Comment: @barakmanos Edited.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345662/prove-that-dfrac-left-5125-1-right-left-525-1-right-is-composit

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks!

Comment: Strangely enough, it has [$5$ prime factors](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1t6tgbhp2i).